# Replace segment with ambient noise in Audacity

Tags: macos, audio, video-editing, audacity, sound-editing

I have an video recording where the audio part consists of people speaking and various ambient noise, where I would like to remove some of the spoken parts.

I am not a sound engineer pro, but I thought the simple and best approach would be to overwrite the spoken parts with ambient noise from another part of the video with some trial and error.

However Audacity does not have any way to "overwrite" one audio segment with another without having to mark the two segments byte-perfect by hand while copying, which seems very hard.

The audio would thus most likely become out of sync with the video when I join them together after finishing the audio work. Moreover, this seems like an unsafe and wrong way to work.

At any rate, how can I achieve my goal of removing the spoken parts, using Audacity or any other non-commercial software (I'm on a Mac)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make a second audio track with the replacement ambient noise (you can copy and paste between tracks). You can then fade out the speaking and fade in the noise. That way, you don't have to chop your primary audio track so the length won't change.

Comment: Good call! I'll try that, and look out for other suggestions that pop up here!